# Getting the data from a List into a grid view in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-log

I am trying to parse an event log file into a `dataGridView` in `Windows Forms`. 
I need to put a list of EventLogEntries `public static List<EventLogEntry> _LogEntries { get; private set; }` into a grid view.
I believe dataGridView would work, but listBox may too.

> I need to get the data from my List `_LogEntries` into a grid view in windows forms. How would I do that?

Below is the code from the `MainForm.cs` for `Windows Forms`

```
    private List<Foo> ComputerName = new List<Foo>();
    private List<Foo> EventId = new List<Foo>();
    private List<Foo> EventType = new List<Foo>();
    private List<Foo> SourceName = new List<Foo>();
    private List<Foo> Message = new List<Foo>();

    class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string bar_;
        public string Bar
        {
            get { return bar_; }
            set
            {
                bar_ = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Bar");
            }
        }

        public Foo(string bar)
        {
            this.Bar = bar;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return bar_;
        }
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bs = new BindingSource(ds, "Events");
        Foo foo1 = new Foo("TEST PC");
        ComputerName.Add(foo1);

        parser.ReadEventLog();
        bs.DataSource = parser._LogEntries;
        //Bind fooList to the dataGridView
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        //I can see bar1 in the listbox as expected

        this.Invoke(pbHandler, new object[] { 100, 100 });
    }

    // Open the log file
    private void OpenFile()
    {
        string evlLocation = "";
        // Show file open dialog
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Create a dataset for binding the data to the grid.
            ds = new DataSet("EventLog Entries");
            ds.Tables.Add("Events");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("ComputerName");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("EventId");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("EventType");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("SourceName");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("Message");
            // Start the processing as a background process
            evlLocation = openFile.FileName;
            parser.setLogLocation(openFile.FileName);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(openFile.FileName);
        }
    }
```

parser class from EventLogParser.cs below

```
    public static class parser
{
    public static string EvlLocation { get; set; }
    public static string evlLocationManual = "K:\\Event Log\\Test\\Test.evt";
    public static List<EventLogEntry> _LogEntries { get; private set; }

    static parser()
    {
        _LogEntries = new List<EventLogEntry>();
    }

    public static void ReadEventLog()
    {
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(EvlLocation);
        EventLogEntryCollection eventLogEntries = eventLog.Entries;
        int eventLogEntryCount = eventLogEntries.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLogEntries.Count; i++)
        {
            EventLogEntry entry = eventLog.Entries[i];
            //Do Some processing on the entry
        }
        _LogEntries = eventLogEntries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().ToList();
    }

    public static void ParseTest()
    {
        evlLocationManual = "K:\\Event Log\\Test\\Test.evt";
        ReadEventLog();
    }

    public static void setLogLocation(string input)
    {
        EvlLocation = input;
    }
}

public static class EventLogEntryCollection_Container
{
    public static void testCollection()
    {
        string myLogName = "_log";

        // Create an EventLog instance and assign its source.
        EventLog _log = new EventLog();
        _log.Source = "%Program Files (x86)%\\EventLogParser\\ImportedEventLogs\\" + varBank.logInput;

        // Write an informational entry to the event log.
        _log.WriteEntry("Successfully created a new Entry in the Log");
        _log.Close();

        // Create a new EventLog object.
        EventLog myEventLog1 = new EventLog();
        myEventLog1.Log = myLogName;

        // Obtain the Log Entries of "_log".
        EventLogEntryCollection _logCollection = _log.Entries;
        _log.Close();

        // Copy the EventLog entries to Array of type EventLogEntry.
        EventLogEntry[] _logEntryArray = new EventLogEntry[_logCollection.Count];
        _logCollection.CopyTo(_logEntryArray, 0);
        IEnumerator myEnumerator = _logEntryArray.GetEnumerator();
        while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            EventLogEntry myEventLogEntry = (EventLogEntry)myEnumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

> I was able to fix some errors, but now when I call `ReadEventLog()` it the throws `an exception of type **System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code**

Comment: Have you ran this at all?  Are you getting errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: I have ran it, it breaks at the line `bs.DataSource = parser._LogEntries;` with an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'

Comment: You're new here so it's not a problem, but in the future you'll want to include those errors in your question, it helps people answer :)

Anyway,  I never see `parser` get defined anywhere.. is that part of the problem?

Comment: No I apologize it is in a different .cs file.

Comment: I put it below the other code snippet

Comment: can you add the definition of `EventLogEntry` too?

Comment: You get an exception in parser::ReadEventLog but you don't want to post the whole function? Just a `//Do Some processing on the entry`. And most of the code you actually posted, doesn't seem to be used here anyway.

Comment: Your `worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object, RunWorkerCompletetdEventArgs)` function hints me to believe, you are using asynchronous functionality. Be aware that you can not and must not call ReadEventLog concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your static `_LogEntries` variable of `parser` class in proper way :

```
public static List<EventLogEntry> _LogEntries = new List<EventLogEntry>();
```

You can initialize your static property in static constructor so that it  would make it has been initialized before its usage.

```
public static List<EventLogEntry> _LogEntries { get; private set; }

static parser()
{ 
     _LogEntries = new List<EventLogEntry>();
}
```

Comment: I don't see where exactly did you intialize.

Comment: The top of parser class

Comment: Ahh, you just updated your code. Is still throwing that error?

Comment: Updated answer to initiaze static property in static constructor. please test with static intializer !!!

Comment: You are getting another exception which is about having null value in variable which you are working with.